# Parsing object to match the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

When i'm receiving query string in any of my REST endpoint (koa-router), each value of query string object parameter is string (obviously):

```
{
  count: "120",
  result: "true",
  text: "ok"
}
```

Inside my codebase i have an Interface to represent query string object:

```
interface Params {
  count: number;
  result: boolean;
  text: string;
}
```

I want to "parse" query string object where all the values are string to match this interface. What is the best practices for doing so?

Comment: you can jsut assign it to a typed variable

Comment: I assume resut is jsut a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems strange to get numbers and booleans as strings since JSON supports unquoted values for both as number and boolean values

`JSON.parse()` has an optional `reviver` callback argument that you could use in a request interceptor so you could normalize string  numbers and booleans before they every get to your interface

```js
const data = `{
  "count": "120",
  "resut": "false",
  "text": "ok"
}`

const reviver = (key, value) => {
   if(typeof value === 'string' && !isNaN(value)){
       return Number(value)
   }else if(value === 'true' || value === 'false'){
       return value === 'true' ? true : false;
   }   
   return value;
}

console.log(JSON.parse(data, reviver ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, going to do some experiments with your solution. It’s all string because this is how it works when you passing arguments through query string (string in url after “?”)

Comment: By the way, data is JavaScript object, not JSON

Comment: It isn't in an  interceptor before it has been parsed. The `data` in my answer is JSON

Comment: Well, to clarify some stuff, even if query string gets parsed into object, you can still write `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), reviver )`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to map the input to the expected interface which means converting each property to the expected type.

```
function toParams(input:any) : Params {
    var o = typeof input === "string" 
            ? JSON.parse(input) 
            : input;
    o.count = +o.count;
    o.result = o.result === "true" ? true : false;
    return o as Params;
}
```

It would be possible for you to instantiate a default instance of `Params` with all the properties set then you can loop over them and verify each property is the same type on the converted object.

```
function toInterface(example:any, input:any) {
    Object.keys(example).forEach(function(key,index) {
        if (!input[key]) return;
        let exampleType = typeof example[key];
        let inputType = typeof input[key];
        if (exampleType !== inputType) {
            if (exampleType == "string") input[key] = input[key] + "";
            if (exampleType == "number") input[key] = +input[key];
            if (exampleType == "boolean") input[key] = input[key] === "true" ? true : false;
            // Any other cases
        }
    });
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Sure, it’s pretty simple to do so, but it’ll get messy as soon as you you will have more attributes in input object, so I’m wondering if there’s any best practices . By the way, input is an object, so I guess it should have a type of any?

Comment: @Src - It would be possible for you to instantiate a default instance of `Params` with all the properties set then you can loop over them and verify each property is the same type on the converted object.